# Python PGP Encrypt with Public Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pgp, openpgp

### **Python PGP Encrypt with Public Key**

I already tried with PGP, but it showed an error with my public key, then I tried with another one and I didn’t have any problem, but it still showed me and error with my Public Key.
The Public Key’s provider told me that everything is ok, and they had done other intregations and they don’t have any problems.
I don’t know if my process is incomplete or there is a problem with the PGP.

**My Code**

```
def pgpy_encrypt(key_blob, data):        
        fkey = False
        key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_blob(key_blob)
        key._require_usage_flags = False        
        message = pgpy.PGPMessage.new(data)
        try:
            sessionkey, enc_message = key.encrypt(message)
            print(enc_message.is_encrypted)
            print('enc_message.is_encrypted')
            print(enc_message.is_encrypted)
            print('enc_message.message')
            print(enc_message.message)        
            if enc_message.is_encrypted :
                return enc_message.message
        
        except pgpy.PGPError as e:
            print('ERROR ' + e)
        return False
```

**The Public Key**

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP Command Line v10.3.2 (Build 12343) (AIX)
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=3w0y
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

**Response**

`<IntegrityProtectedSKEDataV1 [tag 18][v1] at 0x2058a1d3eb0>`

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could move the comment-line before the BEGIN marker.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond It doesn't work. I have the same problem.